# JAR SPRING @autowired

Tags: spring, jar

I create a java archive and i would like integrate this on my application.

on my principal application :

ApplicationContext.xml :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.chomage" />
```

ChomageController.java :

```
@Controller
@Path("/chomage")
public class ChomageController {

   @Autowired
   ChomageService chomageService;

   @Autowired
   OrganisationService organisationService;
}
```

On my java archive :

appConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.test.jarPatrimoine")
public class AppConfig {

}
```

OrganisationService.java

```
public interface OrganisationService {
  //Functions
}
```

OrganisationServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class OrganisationServiceImpl implements OrganisationService 
  //Functions
}
```

When i start my tomcat server, i have the next error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'chomageController': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'organisationService';
nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 
'com.test.jarPatrimoine.service.OrganisationService' available: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency 
annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are there any other classes implementing **OrganisationService**? If so you need to add @Qualifier annotation to inject the right implementation.

```
@Autowire
     @Qualifier("thequalifyingbean") 
     OrganisationService organisationService;
```

also use @Controller for your controller class instead of @Component

Comment: I just watched how work the @qualifier, it's an annotation used when we have several classes that implement an interface, and we want to inject dependencies using this interface. in my case, i have only one classe that implement an interface.

Comment: why have you named your controller classs @component? shouldn't it be @Controller?

Comment: yes it's better, but @component is a generic stereotype for any Spring-managed component ? i'm going change it for to stay logical.

Answer (score 0):

Spring is looking for `com.vnf.jarPatrimoine.service.OrganisationService`, but scan is configured as `@ComponentScan("com.test.jarPatrimoine")`. You might have to change it.

Comment: sorry, it's an error on my post. My scan and my package is the same.